# How to make flexible database for Spring MVC project

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I want to make flexible database design for a Spring-mvc application, I mean that I want for example let user delete or add some attributes on the application withou disturbing it.
 For example: 
 User want to add "adress mail" to his costumer or he want to delete "postal code" because he don't need this information ...etc 
Something like that. 
Is any body has an idea how to make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use schemaless database, for example [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). With [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) you can persist maps that will give you flexibility you need:

```
@Document
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;   
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    ...
```

}

Even though it is doable, I am not convinced if your design is valid. You can persist custom attributes in DB, but showing them in GUI at some point, when you need to customize look and feel for particular field it can become quite frustrating issue.

Comment: Thank you, Ok I want to build an ERP with flexible database, have you any ideas to do this?

Comment: Building ERP is totally out of the scope of this question, and you would need to ask more detailed questions. ERP is just a type of system solving particular business requirements.